# Count number of occurrences in Pandas with a specified list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of possible integer numbers:

```
item_list = [0,1,2,3]
```

and some of the numbers do not necessarily will appear in my dataframe. For example with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]})
```

executing

```
df['a'].value_counts()
```

will yield

```
0 5
1 2
2 1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

but I am interested in all occurrences of all my 'item_list = [0,1,2,3]', so basically, I would like to see something like:

```
0 5
1 2
2 1
3 0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

where the first column is 'item_list'

How to get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert values to [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations):

```
item_list = [0,1,2,3]
df.a = df.a.astype('category', categories=item_list)
print (df['a'].value_counts())
0    5
1    2
2    1
3    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

With [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and parameter `fill_value`:

```
print (df['a'].value_counts().reindex(item_list, fill_value=0))
0    5
1    2
2    1
3    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: is it possible to count number of NaNs as categorical variables as well?

Comment: `NaN` in categorical is `-1`, so need back mapping

Comment: can you show how to implement it? (what is back mapping?)

Comment: got it! simply: df['a'].fillna(-1)

Comment: Yes, it is the simpliest ;)

Comment: got problem: TypeError: _astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories' ???

Comment: Hmm, then you can alternative solution `df.a = pd.Categorical(df.a, categories=item_list)` - check [object creation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#object-creation)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use reindex:

```
 df['a'].value_counts().reindex(item_list).fillna(0)
```